# Does Intel RST Smart Response work with a PCIe drive coupled with a SATA HDD?

Tags: raid, intel-rst, smart-response

I purchased a laptop 2 years ago with a 128GB SATA M2 SSD (for the OS) with a 2TB SATA mechanical drive. From factory it was installed with an *Intel RST* configuration that accelerated the mechanical drive speeds with the use of cache and the primary SSD. I believe it's the *Smart Response Tecnology*.

Now I have decided to upgrade the SATA SSD and I've purchased a bigger (1TB) faster PCIe SSD. But I wonder if I will be able to use Intel Smart Response to keep accelerating my secondary SATA mechanical drive. My concern has to be with it being a PCIe drive as I believe Intel RST works with a RAID like configuration, and as far as my understanding goes RAID works only with SATA. Does Intel RST work that way? Can anyone shed a light as how and what are the hardware requirements for Intel RST and specifically for their Smart Response Tecnology?

This is my laptop current drive setup:

> Primary Drive: SK hynix SC311 SATA 128GB

> Secondary Drive: ST2000LM015-2E8174 (Mechanical 2TB)

This is my intented setup:

> Primary Drive: SK hynix Gold P31 1TB PCIe NVMe SSD

> Secondary Drive: ST2000LM015-2E8174 (Mechanical 2TB)

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using a 1TB SSD as a cache for a 2TB HDD.

In any case,
[Smart Response Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Response_Technology)
has been discontinued by Intel since 2017 in favor of Intel's own solution,
Intel Optane.

This means that Intel RST Smart Response is irrelevant to your new setup.
Don't try to use it (and you probably can't without causing problems).